# What the function of checking graph's length(weight) between two nodes in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I make a Graph by networkx, and it is like that:
[image]

now I want to check the distance(weight) between two points, for example point 6 and 7?

Is there some simple syntax can search it like, Graph[6][7]['length']?

Comment: I only find the function: p = nx.shortest_path_length(chr_MST, source='13',target='14') however, both distances shows integer, it is strange, because all distance is less than 1,for example: 0.003305 in distance matrix

Comment: I got the function: Graph['0']['1']["weight"] it can return the weight between two nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package
https://pypi.org/project/graph-theory/
Check the gd3.distance(n1,n2)

Comment: Thanks for your help again, but it is better for me to use networkx package directly.